# Find gaps in mysql Time

Tags: mysql

I have a table "channel_001" with timestamp column Time, and i did separate it by 10 minutes.

```
2013-01-01;00:10:04;
2013-01-01;00:20:00;
2013-01-01;00:30:02;
2013-01-01;00:40:04;
```

But there are missing datas. How can i detect a missing row? And then insert a row there?!

For example:

```
2013-01-01;00:10:04;
2013-01-01;00:20:00;
2013-01-01;00:30:02
2013-01-01;00:40:04;
2013-01-01;01:00:02;
```

then it would be missing:

```
2013-01-01;00:50:00;
```

I was thinking of using Join the table to itself, but im new in SQL and too much of a novice to finde the answere alone.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are there missing rows? And what's that semi-colon?

Comment: semi-colon becous of the out format:Delimited text. These Datas are the active power  consumed by individual appliences. And sometimes: when nobody was at home -> no data is rocorded. Or it was a mistake.

Comment: But why do you need to check first?

Comment: because of the accuracy of my prediction, what I'll do with MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

You can find rows that don't have a "next" time with something like:

```
select c.*
from channel_001 c
where not exists (select 1
                  from channel_001 c2
                  where c2.timestamp > c.timestamp + interval 9 minute and
                        c2.timestamp < c.timestamp + interval 11 minute
                 );
```

If your table is large (tens of thousands of rows), you will probably want to use variables.  The following code gets the previous timestamp:

```
select c.*,
       (case when (@tmp := @prevts) is null then null
             when (@prevts := timestamp) is null then null
             else @tmp
        end) as prev_timestamp
from channel_001 c cross join
     (select @prevts := 0, @tmp := 0) vars
order by timestamp;
```

You can use this as a subquery to get gaps that are outside your range.

Comment: For separating the data by 10 minutes, i did write:                                                              select DATE(time) as Date, DATE_FORMAT(time,'%T') as Time, avg(verbrauch) as Watt from channel_007 where MONTH(time) = '01' AND YEAR(time) = '2014' group by ((60/10) * HOUR(time)+ FLOOR( MINUTE(time) / 10 )), MONTH(time), DAY(time);                                                         how can i join these two queries? thx